# How do I use Jersey container filter to modify form parameters

Tags: java, jersey

I am using Jersey 1.5, and want to transform an older API to a newer one.

I want to use a container filter to modify the incoming request. This requires that I am able to modify the form parameters. So far I am unable to do so.

My filter:

```
public class Filter implements ContainerRequestFilter  {
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest cr) {
       this.logger.debug(("media type: " + cr.getMediaType().toString()));
       this.logger.debug("before form params: " + cr.getFormParameters().toString());
       cr.getFormParameters().add("test", "test");
       this.logger.debug("after form params: " + cr.getFormParameters().toString());
       return cr;
    }
}
```

Curl:

```
curl -d "hello=world" http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

The output:

```
22:05:38.250 [163501009@qtp-1025542363-0] DEBUG Filter - media type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
22:05:38.250 [163501009@qtp-1025542363-0] DEBUG Filter - before form params: {hello=[world]}
22:05:38.250 [163501009@qtp-1025542363-0] DEBUG Filter - after form params: {hello=[world]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: check cr.getMediatype. It HAS TO be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" otherwise getFormParameters returns just "new Form()".

Comment: Thanks for the response (and sorry for delayed reply). I updated my question with extra information - using Jersey 1.5, and content type is in fact "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: can you update to Jersey 1.13?

Comment: Updated, seeing the same thing.

Comment: Hm, looks like implementation always returns new form, even for consecutive calls; getFormParameters parses request body and extracts parameters from it. So.. you could modify that instead or consider some other way how to pass these params into your application.

Comment: Thanks Pavel - if you make an answer out of that comment I'll accept it. I ended up wrapping the request object to get the behavior I needed.